# Angular passing parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

when i am passing the a parameter to the getActiveId function in the ng-click

```
<span class="col ion-ios7-heart-outline center" ng- click="getActiveId({{activeSlide.selected}})">
```

it's value become zero in the controller and it's passed in the right value after testing it by the inspect element

```
<span class="col ion-ios7-heart-outline center ng-binding" ng-click="getActiveId(1)"> 1:</span>
```

Comment: try `ng-click="getActiveId(activeSlide.selected)"`, remove space before `click` if it's in actual code also.

Answer (score 6):

You need to drop the curly braces surrounding the parameter.

Here's how you should pass parameters to a function or, in any case, how you invoke functions or call scope objects inside directive's attributes:

```
    <span class="col ion-ios7-heart-outline center" ng-click="getActiveId(activeSlide.selected)">
```

**UPDATE**

To further elaborate why you must drop the double curly braces...
these are used when you want to treat a statement as an expression. When it comes to directive's attributes, these are already expressions, so you must not use double curly braces. Makes sense?

Sometimes you'll find single curly braces inside directive's attributes, and this is used when you want to pass an inline javascript object as a parameter. You will see this often with ng-style directive:

```
    <div ng-style="{color:red}">
```

Answer (score 2):

**ng-click** and all angularjs directives that are native (ng-click - ng-model - ng-option , ...)
 all of them will accept expressions without **two curleybraces** .

So you must eliminate this : **{{}}** from inside of your ng-click
like so :

```
     <span ng-click="getActiveId(activeSlide.selected)">
```

But Notice that if you write a new directive of your own , and if you want to pass in any expression into it , you must use curleyBraces like this :

```
    in your controller: 

    $scope.color="blue";

    in your html :

   <span turnToThisColor="{{color}}"></span>

   // This is a directive that will turn this span color , blue
```

Comment: be aware that directive and directive attributes must follow snake case convention, i.e. if you have a turnToThisColor attribute defined in your directive, on the markup you'll call it turn-to-this-color. The later also applies to the directive name. A directive called myDirective should be called on the markup with <my-directive ...> or <div my-directive>.

Comment: Also...I believe that you're not correct when you claim that if you create a custom directive with a custom attribute you must use curly braces. This is wrong because curly braces can't be used with what already is an expression. Your custom attribute _already_ is an expression, so no curly braces there too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you saing , But I'm sure in my example we must use {{}} to inject color value into the directive
Right ?

Comment: it depends...is turnToThisColor treated as an expression? If it is, then you must drop the curly braces.